# How can I startup Tomcat with a UI dialog

Tags: java, tomcat

I build a server in Tomcat, but my customers are not very strong for computer and English. As we all know, the sign of Tomcat started successfully is a sentence like `Server startup in 6000 ms`. I feel this is not a friendly interface to those who are not good at computer. In one word, are there some ways to start Tomcat as run a JFrame or JDialog application? If not, are there some ideas to make one?

Comment: By "I build a server in Tomcat", do you mean you are developing a web application which is deployed on Tomcat?

Comment: Why your users should start tomcat manually? Did you missed a point that you should have one server (preferably on a separate machine from user machines) and the tomcat should be running all the time on that machine, and users normally cannot start or stop the server manually and only the system administrators can do such operations. If your users have separate tomcats on their machines you are not using any feature of a client-server structure and somehow you missed a point about using a web or application server.

Comment: @STaefi I know your meaning. Actually, my application is a simple one. It is for restaurant project. A web server supports several mobiles or pads with the communication of http. Therefore I need a web server. However, the restaurant will shut down power every night, so I need their waiters have the ability to start up/down the Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on Windows. If you take the [Windows Service Installer binary](http://apache.rediris.es/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.23.exe) and installs as service, you get a tray icon for starting/stoping the server.

[image]

Comment: Could you give me a http address for the installer? The link in your answer cannot link to it.

Comment: Link corrected. Anyway, you will find it on the Tomcat home page https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi